# registered users cannot login asp.net identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, identity

In webforms and mysql, i'm trying to implement Asp.net Identity.
When i register a new user, after registration complete, user login automatically. But when i try to login from login page, user cannot login.
Checked connection strings etc but no solution...
Register as below

```
            var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            var signInManager = Context.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
            var roleManager = Context.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationRoleManager>();
            var user = new ApplicationUser()
            {
                UserName = Email.Text,
                Email = Email.Text,
                AdiSoyadi = txtAdiSoyadi.Text,
                PhoneNumber = txtPhone.Text,
                TcKimlikNo = Convert.ToInt64(tc.Text),
                EmailConfirmed = true,
                isactive = true,
                InsertDate = DateTime.Now,
                PhoneNumberConfirmed = true
            };
            IdentityResult result = manager.Create(user, txtPassword.Text);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                manager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Personel");
                // Hesap onayını ve parola sıfırlamayı etkinleştirme hakkında daha fazla bilgi için lütfen https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771 adresini ziyaret edin.
                string code = manager.GenerateEmailConfirmationToken(user.Id);
                string callbackUrl = IdentityHelper.GetUserConfirmationRedirectUrl(code, user.Id, Request);
                manager.SendEmail(user.Id, "Hesabınızı onaylayın", "Lütfen hesabınızı onaylamak için <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\"> buraya tıklayın</a>.");

                signInManager.SignIn(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
                IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"], Response);
            }
            else
            {
                ErrorMessage.Text = result.Errors.FirstOrDefault();
            }
```

login as below

```
            if (IsValid)
            {
                var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
                var signinManager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationSignInManager>();
                
                var result = signinManager .PasswordSignIn(Email.Text, Password.Text, RememberMe.Checked, shouldLockout: false);
                user = manager.FindByEmail(Email.Text); // always return null
                switch (result)
                {
                    case SignInStatus.Success:
                        IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"], Response);
                        break;
                    case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                        Response.Redirect("/Account/Lockout");
                        break;
                    case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                        Response.Redirect(String.Format("/Account/TwoFactorAuthenticationSignIn?ReturnUrl={0}&RememberMe={1}",
                                                        Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"],
                                                        RememberMe.Checked),
                                          true);
                        break;
                    case SignInStatus.Failure:
                        {
                            if (user == null)
                            {
                                FailureText.Text = "E-Posta adresiniz hatalı";
                                ErrorMessage.Visible = true;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                FailureText.Text = "Şifreniz hatalı";
                                ErrorMessage.Visible = true;
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        FailureText.Text = "Geçersiz oturum açma denemesi";
                        ErrorMessage.Visible = true;
                        break;
                }
            }
```

and ApplicationDBContext

```
    [DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySql.Data.EntityFramework.MySqlEFConfiguration))]
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
              : base("DefaultConnectionMySqlServer", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
            System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new MySqlInitializer());

        }
        static ApplicationDbContext()
        {
            System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new MySqlInitializer());
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            #region General Settings
            modelBuilder.Properties().Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(decimal) && p.Name.Contains("itude")).Configure(p => p.HasPrecision(18, 10));
            #endregion

            // Change TUser to ApplicationUser everywhere else - IdentityUser and ApplicationUser essentially 'share' the AspNetUsers Table in the database:
            EntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationUser> table =
                modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("AspNetUsers");

            table.Property((ApplicationUser u) => u.UserName).IsRequired();
            
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("AspNetRoles");

            #region ApplicationUser Settings
            //ApplicationUser Settings
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Property(p => p.AdiSoyadi).HasMaxLength(255);
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Property(p => p.PhoneNumber).HasMaxLength(30);
            #endregion

            #region actionrights
            modelBuilder.Entity<ActionRights>().Property(p => p.ActionName).HasMaxLength(150);
            #endregion
        }
        
    }
```

ApplicationUserManager and ApplicationSignInManager

```
    public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
            : base(store)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
        {
            var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
            // Configure validation logic for usernames
            manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
            {
                AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
                RequireUniqueEmail = true
            };
            // Configure validation logic for passwords
            manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
            {
                RequiredLength = 6,
                RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
                RequireDigit = true,
                RequireLowercase = true,
                RequireUppercase = true,
            };

            // İki öğeli kimlik doğrulama sağlayıcılarını kaydedin. Bu uygulama, kullanıcıyı doğrulama kodunu alma adımı olarak Telefon ve E-posta kullanır
            // Kendi sağlayıcınızı burada yazıp bağlayabilirsiniz.
            manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Telefon Kodu", new PhoneNumberTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
            {
                MessageFormat = "Güvenlik kodunuz: {0}"
            });
            manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("E-posta Kodu", new EmailTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
            {
                Subject = "Güvenlik Kodu",
                BodyFormat = "Güvenlik kodunuz: {0}"
            });

            // Kullanıcı kilitleme varsayılanlarını yapılandır
            manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
            manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;

            manager.EmailService = new EmailService();
            manager.SmsService = new SmsService();
            var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
            if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
            {
                manager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
            }
            return manager;
        }
    }
    public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser, string>
    {
        public ApplicationSignInManager(ApplicationUserManager userManager, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager) :
            base(userManager, authenticationManager)
        { }

        public override Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUser user)
        {
            return user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync((ApplicationUserManager)UserManager);
        }

        public static ApplicationSignInManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationSignInManager> options, IOwinContext context)
        {
            return new ApplicationSignInManager(context.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>(), context.Authentication);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you step through the code to work out why the user can't log in: user record not found, password validation returns false even when you think it's right, something else?

Comment: As i wrote below found the problem.. it was character set of mysql fields...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem... In mysql, i had set the **username** and **email** fields character set **Latin5** and collation to **latin5_turkish_ci**... when i revert back to **latin1** and **latin1_general_ci** problem solved....